# Why is my Caesar Cipher program not displaying my encrypted message? Resolution is off too?

Tags: python, user-interface

I am creating a Caesar Cipher program for class in Python and I was am getting errors when hitting the encrypt button. Also the sizes of the buttons are all out of whack and I can't figure out how to change that. I am very new to Python so please in simplest terms.

This is one of the errors I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Chandler/Desktop/caesar/CSCI220-Assign2-CaesarEncode-CTL.py", line 67, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/Chandler/Desktop/caesar/CSCI220-Assign2-CaesarEncode-CTL.py", line 44, in main
    while not contains(buttonPoint1, win.getMouse()):
TypeError: contains() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ptIn'
```

but any other additional errors noticed will be helpful as well.

Thanks!

```
from graphics import *


def main():



    width = 300
    height = 150
    win = GraphWin("Caesar Cipher, Chandler Long")


    buttonPoint1 = Point(width/2-80, 9*height/10-15)
    buttonPoint2 = Point(width/2+80, 9*height/10+15)
    button1 = Rectangle(buttonPoint1, buttonPoint2)
    labelB = Text(Point(width/2, 9*height/10), "Cipher")
    label1 = Text(Point(width/6, height/5), "Enter Message:")
    label2 = Text(Point(width/6, 2*height/5),  "Key:")
    label3 = Text(Point(width/6, 3*height/5), "Your Message:")
    labelV = Text(Point(2*width/3, 3*height/5), "")
    input1 = Entry(Point(2*width/3, height/5), width//20)
    input2 = Entry(Point(2*width/3, 2*height/5), 3)
    graphOb = [button1, labelB, label1, label2, input1, input2]
    for graphicsObject in graphOb:
        graphicsObject.draw(win)

    while not contains(buttonPoint1, buttonPoint2, win.getMouse()):
        None
    labelB.setText("Quit")

    try:
        labelV.setText(cipher(textBox1.getText(), int(textBox2.getText())))
    except:
        label3.setText('Error:')
        labelV.setText('Invalid key.')
    label3.draw(win)
    labelV.draw(win)

    while not contains(buttonPoint1, win.getMouse()):
        None
    win.close()

def contains(pt1, pt2, ptIn):
    return pt1.getX() < ptIn.getX() and ptIn.getX() < pt2.getX()
    pt1.getY() < ptIn.getY() and ptIn.getY() < pt2.getY()

def encrypt(message, key):
    cleartext = ""
    letterLow = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    letterCap = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    for char in text:
        if char in lettersLow:
            cleartext = cleartext + chr((ord(char) + key - ord("a")) % 26 + ord("a"))
        elif char in letterCap:
            cleartext = cleartext + chr((ord(char) + key - ord("A")) % 26 + ord("A"))
        else:
            cleartext = cleartext + char
    return cleartext


#end main
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling contains with 2 arguments even though it is defined with three arguments.

```
    while not contains(buttonPoint1, win.getMouse()):
        None
    win.close()

def contains(pt1, pt2, ptIn):
    return pt1.getX() < ptIn.getX() and ptIn.getX() < pt2.getX()
    pt1.getY() < ptIn.getY() and ptIn.getY() < pt2.getY()

File "/Users/Chandler/Desktop/caesar/CSCI220-Assign2-CaesarEncode-CTL.py", line 44, in main
while not contains(buttonPoint1, win.getMouse()):
```

You are missing an **and** in the definition of `contains()`. If you want to have the definition of `contains()` return the full true false value, it should be

```
def contains(pt1, pt2, ptIn):
    return pt1.getX() < ptIn.getX() and ptIn.getX() < pt2.getX() and
    pt1.getY() < ptIn.getY() and ptIn.getY() < pt2.getY()
```

As you have it, it will return the value of the first line and ignore the second line.

Another possible error may be

```
for char in text:
```

I do not see where text has been initialized and passed into `encrypt(message, key)` You do not use the input argument `message`. It may be that you meant to use one where you used the other.

Comment: @Chandler Long There are a number of errors in your code. First fix them.